# How can I repair a Petri 1.9 Color Corrected Super with a stuck exposure counter?

Tags: repair, diy, old-cameras, rangefinder

I recently bought a Petri 1.9 Color Corrected Super which is almost fully-functional, except for the exposure counter. It is stuck between the position "S" and -2.

Do you have any suggestions for possible repair?

Comment: Found the initial "reparation" version very funny, was about to make a comment about politics :)